# How do I change the rootfs file system type used for the sdcard image in yocto?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I'm making my own image recipe and would still like to output the sdcard image as before for my iMX6, however I would like to move it from being based on an ext3 file system to ext4 (or potentially btrfs). For the life of me I can't work out what I need to override to achieve this. Adding ext4 as well as sdcard to the IMAGE_FSTYPES variable in my recipe in my own layer merely gives me both a .ext3 and .ext4 output, of which the .etx3 one appears to be used for the .sdcard image. Either that or it's ext4 mounting as ext3 at boot time... My image inherits core-image and installs CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL as the basis for my additions.

Any suggestions as to how I *should* be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

meta-fsl-arm has a custom class for creating the sdcard images, you can read about it in the commit which introduced it:

http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-fsl-arm/commit/classes?id=83534159576f9bf35f05f0b285aec06a7d4ef737

The rootfs written to the sdcard is determined through the `SDCARD_ROOTFS` variable which is typically inherited in the imx*.conf files from the included imx-base.inc, i.e. in the current master branch of meta-fsl-arm I see line 35 & 36:
    SDCARD_ROOTFS ?= "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${IMAGE_NAME}.rootfs.ext3"
    IMAGE_FSTYPES ?= "tar.bz2 ext3 sdcard"

It should be sufficient to append ext4 to IMAGE_FSTYPES and set SDCARD_ROOTFS appropriately, i.e. (**untested**):

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES_append = " ext4"
SDCARD_ROOTFS = "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${IMAGE_NAME}.rootfs.ext4"
```