# Yocto - How do I change the rootfs file system type

Tags: embedded-linux, bitbake, rootfs, squashfs, yocto-wic

I'm trying to build vdi image with squashfs rootfs, but cannot find where to change current ext4 fs into squash. Closest solutions I found is here: [How do I change the rootfs file system type used for the sdcard image in yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127363/how-do-i-change-the-rootfs-file-system-type-used-for-the-sdcard-image-in-yocto)
But I don't feel like this answered my problem. I am able to build .rootfs.squashfs and .rootfs.wic.vdi. Is it possible to build .rootfs.wic.vdi with squashfs root using bitbake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the configuration file of the `wic` command: if you search in the yocto tree or look at the logs (use `bitbake -D ...` to get more logs), you will probably find a file name suffixed by `.wks`. This is the file of directives passed to `wic`.

In yocto environment, `wic` can be used on the command line. For example, to get the manual overview:

```
$ wic help overview


NAME
    wic overview - General overview of wic

DESCRIPTION
    The 'wic' command generates partitioned images from existing
    OpenEmbedded build artifacts.  Image generation is driven by
    partitioning commands contained in an 'Openembedded kickstart'
[...]
```

The `--source` option triggers a plugin. The manual is probably not up to date and you may need to go into the source code of the plugins (`wic` is written in python) which is located in something like: *...poky/scripts/lib/wic*. There you will see, the code managing the "rootfs" plugin in *partition.py*. You will see that only a reduced set of file system types are supported. Hopefully, *squashfs* is part of them. Here is the code snippet managing it:

```
    def prepare_rootfs_squashfs(self, rootfs, oe_builddir, rootfs_dir,
                                native_sysroot, pseudo):
        """
        Prepare content for a squashfs rootfs partition.
        """
        extraopts = self.mkfs_extraopts or '-noappend'
        squashfs_cmd = "mksquashfs %s %s %s" % \
                       (rootfs_dir, rootfs, extraopts)
        exec_native_cmd(squashfs_cmd, native_sysroot, pseudo=pseudo)
```

The preceding shows that `wic` calls [mksquashfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mksquashfs.1.html) tool to build the file system.

Example of [howto](https://pretalx.com/media/yocto-project-summit-2020/submissions/GVU8HS/resources/Norbert_Kaminski_Wic_plugin_devel_0Lszv3V.pdf).

Comment: I found this directory in /meta-yocto-bsp/wic and made some changes in beaglebone-yocto.wks file 
current code is following:

`part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4 --fixed-size 32 --sourceparams="loader=u-boot" --use-uuid
part / --source rootfs --ondisk sda --fstype=squashfs --label root --align 1024 --use-uuid
bootloader --append="rootfstype=squashfs console=ttyS0,115200"
`   
I changed fstab as well, but after bitbake my root is still ext4. Am I missing something?

Comment: After bitbake there were no changes in the image, no tasks needed to be rerun .

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more information. You may be able to run wic directly on the command line passing to it the right parameters and config file.

Comment: This all is true and very helpful especially the presentation you shared. Thank you for that. I found out that I didn't change correct file I believe it is suppose to be common.wks.inc and qemux86-directdisk.wks located at poky/scripts/lib/wic/canned-wks/.
After cleaning images `bitbake -c clean <IMAGE>` and building `bitbake <IMAGE>` I got an error at common.wks.inc: SquashFS does not support LABEL. I managed to find actual patch for this https://www.mail-archive.com/openembedded-core@lists.openembedded.org/msg114885.html 
Code in partition.py is the same as you described above.

Comment: So far every part command I found with squashfs had --label so I don't think it's the real problem:
`part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=squashfs --label root --align 1024`

Comment: I was able to build my project without --label argument, so far it's working as it should be. Thanks!